# Does one also get reputation for editing questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, editing, suggested-edits

I recently added a link to the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20488/a-question-on-the-proof-of-the-de-bruijn-erdos-theorem) posted on the De Bruijn-Erdos theorem. For some reason I received two reputation, but this doesn't seem to be one of the cases listed in the FAQ reputation section for the main site.

This is the first time I edited a question, since I don't have the required 2000 to do so quickly, and this surprised me. I'm curious, is this supposed to happen, or was it just a fluke? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is a [new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep) to give 2 points to a user for suggesting an edit that is approved.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I didn't know that had been added so recently.

Comment: Oh, that's why users have been suggesting so many edits lately... I thought they were just being nice.

Comment: But a person gets the +2 only if s/he doesn't have the 2000 reputation needed to edit without approval, right? So it's a means of getting more people to 2000?

Comment: @TomAu: That's true, editing without approval doesn't give points. It could be seen partly as a means of getting more people to 2000, but I don't know what all the SE team had in mind.  You might find more explanation searching meta.stackoverflow.com, and you might be interested in [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/editing-answers-does-not-give-reputation-anymore)