# Wanting to share credit with answer editor

Tags: discussion, reputation, editing

I answered the following question recently: [Which one of these options is false?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203606/which-one-of-these-options-is-false/2203627#2203627)

If one sees the  edit history of the answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2203627/revisions

It can be seen that while my answer to the question was at the least satisfactory (to somebody, maybe not the questioner), a kind moderator turned it into an excellent post with a revamp, so that it received more up votes after the edit than it did before the edit (which was positive, so that means the answer was at least acceptable to somebody). I am grateful to him.

My question is the following : I would like to, on my own accord, share some of the credit for this wonderful post with the editor of the answer. I have seen some apparently similar questions on meta, like the following :

[Does one also get reputation for editing questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/does-one-also-get-reputation-for-editing-questions)

[Editing answers does not give reputation anymore](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/editing-answers-does-not-give-reputation-anymore) (here the answer given is excellent)

[Why should someone receive reputation if someone else edits their terrible question into a good one?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23703/why-should-someone-receive-reputation-if-someone-else-edits-their-terrible-quest) (the difference being that a terrible question is discussed here, while I am discussing a satisfactory answer).

[Edits that Substantially Extend Answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/edits-that-substantially-extend-answers?rq=1) (This is not true of the moderator in question : first of all, he kindly requested me to reject his edit if it significantly departed from my intention, which was never the case : he just rewrote my argument and removed the entire example in the first part, which I thought was no wrong).

[Question owner: author or editor?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/question-owner-author-or-editor) (I am basically wishing that I can transfer ownership of my answer to the moderator to give him the credit for coming up with the answer).

These all differ from my question in one important aspect :

> Here, *I* am the one wanting to share my reputation with the moderator, on my own accord, but in all the above questions, it is the site itself awarding reputation via some algorithm. This is important, because the machine cannot make out what a *significant* or **comprehensive** edit is, that is relative to the person whose answer is being edited (as was in my case).

How do I give credit to the editor more? Is there a way of attributing some of the votes to him, or transferring the answer in his name, so that the credit goes to him rather than me?

Also, having completed one year on this site recently, I would like to thank all those who have helped me bed into the site in this superlative journey.

I would like to ask if the question I have asked is appropriate to the meta site (although the responses and votes will tell me that, I would love a honest response from anybody).

Comment: Info: This is [already asked on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89387/awarding-a-bounty-to-an-editor#comment577333_187692), and the answer that suggests "bounty another answer" is [not well received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89387/awarding-a-bounty-to-an-editor#comment577333_187692).

Comment: @InanimateBeing im sorry ive been busy today. 14 hour day. i will get back to you tomorrow. promise

Comment: @InanimateBeing Over the past two or so years, congratulations involving reputation, views, and general MSE stats ($1.5$ millionth question occurred recently) were all frowned upon. While I feel that this may not be necessary because meta isn't overflowing with content or needs moderation, the general reaction is that there is perhaps no need to look at these statistics with any pride anymore. That might be the negative reaction's origin. I don't think the congratulations thread, despite being open, will entertain any more answers which actually receive a good response anymore.

Comment: @InanimateBeing Not that I am aware of it.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find an answer that the user wrote, and you think is excellent, and award it with a bounty of your choosing.

Comment: In  this case, that works, since the moderator in question has written many such answers. What would I do if, say a new user did the same?  Or,  for example, a user who has had good reputation for questions but not for answers? Also, I would like to ask if the above question is appropriate to  the meta website.

Comment: Do you have an example of a user with high reputation but no good answers?

Comment: @AsafKaragila there are users…[this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/76878/laila-podlesny) , [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/92728/shiquan) , [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/46347/sonicboom) , […………](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/649401)

Comment: @Fawad: Okay, I guess we have different standards for "high reputation". But let me amend my query. Do you have an example of a high reputation user without good answers which actively edits answers in a significant kind of way, enough to merit "sharing reputation"?

Comment: @Asaf I don't see why making answer Wiki is not good in this situation. If someone edit post,then person with highest edits name will be shown. I don't know any user who actively edit posts with no good answers.

Comment: @Fawad: How does that reward the editor? If you just want to give credit, you can always add a footnote or a disclaimer on the top part of the question with a link to the user page.

Comment: @Fawad: Yes. I am well aware of that feature. How does that change my previous comment?

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are right, in that I am not able to find any such users. However, I have awarded the bounty as you had said, to the moderator. Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: For what it's worth, Did is not a moderator.

Comment: Not worth anything, expect the fact that if he were one, then he's certainly doing his job.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: What is it that you think moderators are supposed to do?

Comment: Well, I as a moderator am doing the following : editing posts, voting to close questions, reviewing few users aside, I want to invite users to this website, make it more attractive. When you have such people around as Did (I can name a few more, but some of them may mind, so I won't do so), then it makes my job much more easier, because I know there are people moderating the site who want a better quality of answers, and more people to start appreciating the website and using it properly. That is my aim. You may freely criticise me (though I may cry if you do so very harshly!)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: But you are not a moderator. You are a user. Moderators have additional powers, duties, and privileges. Moderators also have a diamond symbol by their user name.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So why does it say in the box on the left in the review page : "This site is modearated by you"? Once again, as far as it's concerned, the above is what I strive to do on the website, moderator or not.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: This is a matter of jargon. Moderators are specific users whose duties are beyond the level of moderation you and I do. These are people chosen by the community, not appointed by SE. I was confused by your use of the word. That is all.

Comment: I see, yes, certainly I too was confused when you said that I wasn't "moderating" the website, when I thought I've been doing that for quite some time. Thank you for the clarification. I'll look for this diamond next time!

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Here's the [list of official moderators](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) for this site.

Answer (score -2):

Make your post community Wiki.  So person who made most edit his name will be shown on that post. I know it's hard because no one will get reputation points from it.